# What happens with computer accounts in case of temporary resources?

Tags: virtual-machines, active-directory, cloud

First off, last time, I was administering any AD was years ago. Back then every domain-joined computer would create a computer account as well as the user needed a user account.

How does this work today with temporary computers, like users domain-joining their own hardware or wiring up a temporary VM in the cloud for a day or two and then deleting them.

Obviously such resources are not created by the IT department, and specifically, they are not removed from the AD anyhow, but rather just disappear (vm deleted, user got themselves a new computer and no longer uses the old one, maybe done a full re-install, etc.)

Does the AD just accumulate orphaned computer account and how is it cleaned?

My question goes to both the on-premise, as well as the azure-hosted AD.

Comment: When you mention "temporary" devices joining AD, do you perhaps have [Workplace Join](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/Workplace-Join) in mind?

Comment: Not perfectly sure, for private devices, that probably is it. But our IT department has created an azure VM image that does domain-joining. So that one might do a proper join. Honestly, I'm interested in knowing the state of things today

Comment: Aside from the addition of workplace join, nothing is different than what you know. If a machine is joined to the domain, an object is created. It will stay there until removed. If the machine is un-joined from the domain on the client end, the object will be disabled, but not removed.

Comment: Thank you very much. For workplace join, does it mean, that one does not actually create computer accounts?

Comment: I don't believe it does. I've not used it though. A quick Internet search would quickly answer that though.